# Solus 1.1 adding bidirectional clipboard

Tags: virtualbox, clipboard, solus

I have Solus 1.1 installed in VirtualBox (host Ubuntu 14.04). I managed to install the guest additions using https://wiki.solus-project.com/VirtualBox,
but at it says:

> Installing graphics libraries and desktop services components ...fail!
>   (See the log file `/var/log/vboxadd-install-x11.log` for more information.)

And that log files contains only:

> VirtualBox Guest Additions installation, Window System and desktop setup
>   Could not set up the VBoxClient desktop service.
>   To start it at log-in for a given user, add the command `VBoxClient-all`
>   to the file `.xinitrc` in their home directory.

There is no `VBoxClient-all`.

I can resize the Window, but the one thing that is still missing is being able to cut-and-paste the clipboard (It is already set to bidirectional in the VB General-Advance tab). How can I do that?

Comment: I added the [tag:solus] tag, please add it to future questions that are Solus specific (only)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try running `VBoxClient --clipboard` and see if you can copy and paste from the client to the host and vv.

If that works you might want to just add that command as a line to your `~/.bashrc`. It doesn't hurt to be invoked multiple times, and I have not been
able to convince Solus to use it from `~/.xinitrc` as the log indicates.

The video [here](https://blackhatinside.wordpress.com/2016/01/04/solus-os-1-0-install-virtualbox-guest-editions/), shows a clean installation (in 1.0) of the Virtualbox guest I have not been able to repeat that yet.